# Can I use paypal express API if my registered account is paypal standard

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

When you register an account in paypal they will ask you what type of account you want to create. I choose business then there are 3 options to choose from.

1. Payments Pro
2. Paypal Standard
3. Paypal Express

I selected Paypal Standard.

Can I still use Paypal express API even if my account is paypal standard?

Thanks,
Defy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can use PayPal Express Checkout. You just get the API credentials from your PayPal account and use those API credentials at express checkout integration.